# Ruby On Rails: How can I create a route to the public/index.html static file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I feel like this should be easy, tho I'm very new to rails I'm struggling trying figure out how to create a route that maps to the static index.html file in the public folder.  Whenever a person goes to the URL "http://myapp.com/directory", I want it to route to the index.html file in the public folder, but I don't know how to construct that route in the routes.rb.

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Comment: This sounds like a weird requirement indeed. Referencing to your comment in U-DONs answer, why don't you tell us the reason why you want to do it that way. What do you ultimately want to achieve? You stated you are new to rails - so please help us helping you find a good solution rather than just something that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes, put `match "/directory" => redirect("/")`

Comment: Does it work with just `redirect("/")`? Sorry, but don't have an environment at hand to test this at the moment.

Comment: sorry, actually that does work, but only locally. when i push to heroku it, it crashes with the "pages does not exist error"

Answer (score 2):

You will want to run:

```
rails generate controller directory index
```

That should create "app/views/directory/index.html.erb". Just copy over everything from index.html to that index.html.erb file and remove the index.html file (or change its name, whatever). In your routes.rb, just write:

```
match "/directory" => directory#index
```

Run your server again after that. You can't route to public/index.html; if you keep that file, your root URL will just automatically grab that file and render it.

Comment: Thanks, U-DON!  I'm ok if the root URL grabs that file, but I also want the myapp.com/directory URL to grab that file as well.  Is there anyway to do this?  I know it's a weird question, but there is a reason I want to do it this way.  Thanks again!